# Swift 3 Core Data - Entity(context:) vs Entity(entity: Location.entity(), insertInto: context)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity, nsmanagedobject

Ive watched the 2016 WWDC Video on Core Data and viewed various tutorials. I have seen various ways of creating an object to persist into the managedObjectContext with the Core Data Framework.

In the example I have `Day` as an entity. I would like to create a new `Day` object for each new day that the user uses the application.

I have come across:

1st option

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Day", into: CoreDataHelper.context)
let object = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: CoreDataHelper.context)
```

2nd option

```
let object = Day(entity: Day.entity(), insertInto: CoreDataHelper.context)
```

3rd option

```
let object = Day(context: CoreDataHelper.context)
```

and know there have been other possibilities people have come up with as well.

What is the difference between the bottom two options, as I did not see a demonstration of the second option in the WWDC Video. Does the third option automatically insert into the managedObjectContext or should there be a certain approach taken to insert the object into the context to then retrieve all objects using the NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: Seems like you have to init() in your Day  class.one with single parameter and one with multiple parameter.?

Comment: @TusharSharma Im sorry, i do not know what you mean. Im just asking for clarification on what is the best approach to create an object and persist it into CoreData

Comment: Correction I mean two initializers in your Day class.It is class right ?? Of type NSManaedObject.??

Comment: @TusharSharma I am not having trouble creating my own class, but understanding how to properly, and most efficiently use the Core Data Framework. Creating an NSManagedObject and persisting the data to the device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second option is the designated initializer on `NSManagedObject`, which `Day` subclasses.

The third option is a convenience initializer defined on `Day` that invokes option 2.

The first option is nonsense.  The first line creates an instance of `Day` inserted into the context, just like option 2 and 3. The second line attempts to create an instance of `Day` by passing **an instance of `Day`**
to a parameter that is expecting an `NSEntityDescription`. I suspect option 1 is supposed to look like:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Day", in: CoreDataHelper.context)
let object = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: CoreDataHelper.context)
```

All of the options have the same result. I'm not sure why there are so many variations. That would be a question only Apple could answer. Hope this was helpful!